# Can protein shake be blamed for not losing weight

Tags: weight-loss, muscle-mass, bellyfat

I'm trying to lose my tummy, I am following a plan. I eat accordingly and stay away from sugar, I do have protein shake post workout, and in work out have my BCAA. It's been a month, I take 1-2 days off from gym also I try to swim (although I'm learning), my weight has been fixated on 80 kg.
The program I am following make sure you lose 2-3 pounds per week. Given everyone's body is different and what the person can lift weight I cannot. Can I blame protein shake or BCAA from keeping me shedding the weight?

Comment: How much calories are you eating per day and how much are you burning? I assume you don't know exactly, which would be a reason why you're not losing weight. To lose weight calorie intake needs to be lower than calorie expenditure. To make this work, you'll have to know both variables and also know how to adjust them. Right now, it seems like you're breaking even. Removing the protein shake could tip the balance in your favor, but so would eating less in general or working out more. You just have to adjust the balance, no matter by which means.

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla how can I find how much cal I m intaking, is there a tool to find out? I was having half kg of chicken in 2 meals or someone half kg in just one meal. That make 5 meals. In total of my daily diet

Comment: there're several sites that allow you to track everything you eat. Most of those also have a database where you can search for whatever you ate and log that into a food diary. The diary should then be able to tell you how much kcal, protein, carbs, fat etc. you ate that day. I'm using fddb.de, which seems to have an english implementation at http://fddb.info/db/en/.

Comment: Have you tried stopping the shake for just one week to see if you start loosing weight? That would answer your question more reliably than people conjecturing about your workout/diet plan.

Comment: @ZeFrenchy nope, I haven't but I can but won't my muscle be sore and not recovering? I did tried supplements a month ago. All I saw was my body  muscled stop snapping up as they were when I was taking supplements. I was told I was having too many supp.

Comment: @zeFrenchy: That could solve the problem at hand, but I like to think that one should _understand_ what one does, especially when it comes to nutrition. "Give a man a fish..." and all that. In addition, removing high quality protein from a diet while trying to lose weight would probably be sub-optimal, as one less slice of bread would achieve the same thing without inhibiting muscle-protein-synthesis and recovery.

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla, the quest for knowledge is a nobel one, but sometimes seeking perfect theoretical solution is used as an excuse to do nothing in practice. As a side note, there is a rather prevalent assumption from many that diet supplementation is the solution to all things. In my opinion, they can be used to optimise an existing sound diet/workout plan. What I'm saying is supplements can not fix a bad routine. Nofel should find the plan that starts working for him *before* looking at expensive diet supplements ... Hint: up your cardio to lose fat!

Comment: There's absolutely no way to answer this question with the information provided.

Comment: @Dave Newton what info you need more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not losing weight because you your calorie intake is greater than your calorie expenditure.

While this isn't directly attributable to your workout shake, they still have calories - albeit nearly 100% protein.

If you which to lose weight but arent, you need to adjust it so you use more calories than you consume. This can either be done by additional exercise in the day ***without*** increasing your calories to compensate or by reducing your calories further.

While the protein shake may seem like an easy target for reducing your calories, as mentioned in the comments, protein is important when eating at a *calorie deficit*. Instead,  **look at reducing your consumption of hidden sugars** in your day such as soda, fruit juice or overly sugary caffeine drinks. Also consider slight decreases in your portion sizes and reducing snacks.

Comment: I don't use soda or juices, if I reduce the portions of my snacks, I feel hungry

Comment: Well, get used to it. Nothing worth having comes easy. And I guarantee you aren't "hungry". Cut the snacks and lose the weight, simple as that.

Comment: what about the thing I heard that body uses it's stored Fats when hungry. Doesn't that count in bad for loosing weight?

Answer (score 0):

Its not a simple as following a plan because someone says so, and expecting it to work perfectly. This isn't a movie. What worked for them might not work for you, and you are intelligent enough to realize this I see.

Staying away from sugar will not be the defining factor in your weight loss goals, what will aid you in your weight loss goals are ACTUALLY working out, which i didn't even see you mention.. and listening to what @LarissaGodzilla just told you.

Comment: working out? I do work out everyday, if that is what you mean. I have days for each 2 muscles to train.

Comment: I see. Now to answer your question,give yourself time and consistency in order to see results. Don't immediately start seeking excuses if your results aren't coming fast enough. Best of Luck

Comment: it's been 1 months +

Comment: That is absolutely nothing. You want serious changes ? Give it a year my friend. No shortcuts in this game, anyone who's word is worth anything will tell you the same.

Comment: my nephew had big tummy than me and in 3 months he is shredded.

Comment: @Macedon93 - Please try to keep conversation items (such as c'mon man) out of your answers, this is not a conversation site.

Answer (score 0):

You should start to see weight lose within a week, if you are doing it properly.  A couple of pound a week, is realistic.  Look at your diet, and exercise program.

There are app that will help you count calories, and help you workout how many calories you require to lose weight.  Myfitnesspal is pretty good.

Don't go lower than recommended, otherwise your metabolism will slow, as your body will think its being starved.

Good luck